# Is it possible to make PHPStorm include necessary files automatically?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a project with lot of files. Normally each file contains one class definition. Currently when I need an instance of object I use loader, which includes necessary file and instantiates it. Such approach though doesn't allow IntelliSense to work properly. And I prefer more readable `new MyObject()` than `$loader->load("MyObject")`.
I use PHPStorm IDE. Is it possible to configure it to add necessary `require_once("some_file.php")` when I use appropriate class type?

Comment: Could you give some examples of your code, I'm assuming that this is more about proper doc blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:
Switch to using the autoload feature of PHP (5+) and then use `new MyObject()`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Solution 2:
Use a live template defined like this:

```
/** @var $CLASSNAME$ $VARNAME$ **/
$VARNAME$ = $loader->load("$CLASSNAME$");
```

You can then choose the class name and the vriable name each time you use the livetemplate.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to add `use` statements automatically [will be available](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1362) in PhpStorm 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a specific project you could always create a template wich includes all you're crap! Ten when you do file-new it will give you a file based on that template.